# Socket Connection Refused

Tags: linux, apache, sockets, debian, port

I am using a new script I bought and I keep getting this socket error:

```
GET https://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/1/?t=1432947339492 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

As far as I am aware the configuration files are correct.

```
socket = io.connect( 'https://127.0.0.1:8081' );
```

and

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'https' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );
io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
console.log( "New client !" );

client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );
    //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    io.sockets.emit( 'message', data);
});

client.on( 'doTrade', function( data ) {
    //console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );
    io.sockets.emit( 'doTrade', data );
});
});

server.listen( 8081 );
```

I tried this (I am using linux, debian):

```
root@Crypto:~# nc 127.0.0.1 8081 < /dev/null; echo $?
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 8081 (tproxy) : Connection refused
1
root@Crypto:~# nc 127.0.0.1 80 < /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Where 0 = open and 1 = closed.

I'm guessing this could be the reason why the connection is getting refused, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Can anyone come up with a solution to stop the connection getting refused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nothing is listening on port 8081. After you start the server, what does:

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 8081
```

show?

Comment: Nothing shows.. just goes onto next command. I think its something to do with the application tproxy binding to the port and hence refusing connections. However I have no idea what it is and don't remember anything about it :S

Comment: I think you are probably right about tproxy. What does this show:         sudo iptables -L -n -t mangle